# jsonp failing gives 404

Tags: jquery, jsonp

to my understanding, this what happens:

1. jsonp simply wraps json in a function.
2. when using jsonp, you have to specify the name of the function used in (1)
3. receive data as a normal josn

is my understanding right ? please correct me if im wrong

if im correct, why doesnt my code work? im trying to access a small local jsonp file but it givs me 404

```
    (function ($) {
    var url = 'dummy.jsonp?callback=?';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'wrapper',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            alert(json);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

dummy.jsonp:

```
wrapper([
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"clark"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "description":"Kent"
   }
])
```

Edit:
turns out @xdazz is right, when I uploaded my file on a public server it was accessed normally
but now how do i fix this to work with relative paths? both this page and dummy.jsonp are in same folder

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: check the url path is right first.

Comment: Why are you specifying `jsonpCallback: 'wrapper'` in the options _and_ `callback=?` in your URL? (Also, I don't think `async:false` works with JSONP, and there's no need for `contentType` because that applies to the _request_ rather than the _response_ and your request has no content.)

Comment: Is the jsonp file world readable? A 404 should mean it can't be found at all. I don't think JQuery could be the adding that error code after receiving something else. But check the request your browser sends out, and the response it gets back. Then open the url from that request directly in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

As your server response looks like that. You should have the `wrapper()` method in your client side.

Add such a function in your client side code,

```
function wrapper(data)
{
  alert(data[0].id);
 }


(function ($) {
var url = 'dummy.jsonp?callback=?';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
        alert(json);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: No, jQuery automatically implements the callback for you.

Comment: @nnnnnn I'm not familiar with that way.. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't make sense to code the `wrapper()` function yourself when jQuery will automatically implement a callback function with the name specified in the `jsonpCallback` option, and it will pass the data through to the success handler.

Comment: It could make sense to implement the jsonp callback yourself just for test purposes, though it's possible JQuery might freak out.